# This tag is in the [frame]

Tags: discussion, tag-disambiguation

The tag [frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/frame) is a bit ambiguous. It tells people to not use it for HTML questions, but there's 248 such questions, and it may be used for other unrelated purposes (there's two cases of it being used about InDesign).